# Internal Server Error in Bugzilla after resetting MySql Password

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, bugzilla

I have reset my mysql password, however now Bugzilla returns an Internal Service Error occasionally when accessing certain pages within Bugzilla. The error goes away when you refresh the page, but it'd be nice it stopped appearing.

I have updated the `$db_pass` variable in Bugzilla's `localconfig` file, rerun `checksetup.pl` and I've tried restarting my mysql server and the issue still occurs. Does anyone know what I could be missing? The error only occurs on certain pages, and like I said usually disappears when I refresh the page.